# Python websocket with FastAPI does not return data immediately

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I created a websocket connection with FastAPI to "stream" data which comes from a tedious calculation. The data chunks should be send as soon as they are available and not altogether at the very end.
In the following code snipped shows my problem simplified. **sleep()** here shall simulate the calculation time between the resulting data.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
import uvicorn
from time import sleep

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/")
async def endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        command = await websocket.receive_text()
        if command == "getData":
            data = {"name": "NAME1", "result": "ABC"}
            await websocket.send_json(data)
            sleep(3)
            data = {"name": "NAME2", "result": "DEF"}
            await websocket.send_json(data)
            sleep(3)
            data = {"name": "NAME3", "result": "GHI"}
            await websocket.send_json(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("api:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Problem is when executing this code the client receives no data for 6 seconds and afterwards all the data is transmitted at once. Why is this and how can I make the data chunks being send back one by one as soon as they are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` is a blocking operation, so even the event loop is suspended in the current thread.

Try using `asyncio.sleep` which is non-blocking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly with `asyncio.sleep`.